# When should a CIVI group be disabled vs deleted?

Tags: groups

I am wondering what the difference between archiving and disabling a Group is? I would like to clean up our list of groups (including Smart Groups) without deleting or affecting any of the historical information related to these groups such as being a part of a specific bulk mailing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I would use the disable feature for that. Deleting is when you want to completely remove everything about it. Civi doesn't really have "archive" the way I think archive means. To me archiving is removing from the database but storing it somewhere else. Disabling keeps it in the same database but hides it from day to day tasks, and let's you restore it.

Comment: Disabling is the best! Especially when you've got too many smart groups and don't need them all.